# Angular js form submits when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-submit

I have an AngularJS form which looks like this:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.update(vm.model)"> 

     .. fields

     <button ng-click="vm.addCluster()">Add</button>

     .. more fields

     <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 

</form>
```

When I click submit it works as expected - `update()` method is called. When I click the button it calls `addCluster()` but after that the form gets submitted and `update()` is called automatically.

Why does it do It and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default action of a button(with no `type` specified) in a form is to submit it, you can set the `type` of the button to `button` to change this behavior

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.addCluster()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can give the button an extra attribute like so

```
<button type="button">Your button</button>
```

The type="button" should prevent the unwanted form submission.